# AWS EC2 instance Application logs

Tags: linux, logging, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

I want to store logs of applications like uWSGI ("/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log") on a device that can be accessed from
multiple instances and can save their logs to that particular device under their own instance name dir.

So does AWS provides any solution to do that....

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of approaches you can take here.  If you want to have an experience that is like writing directly to the filesystem, then you could look at using something like [s3fs](http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) to mount a common S3 bucket to each of your instances.  This would give you more or less a real-time log merge though honestly I would be concerned over the performance of such a set up in a high volume application.

You could process the logs at some regular interval to push the data to some common store.  This would not be real time, but would likely be a pretty simple solution.  The problem here is that it may be difficult to interleave your log entries from different servers if you need to have them arranged in time order.

Personally, I set up a [Graylog](http://graylog2.org/) server for each instance cluster I have, to which I log all my access logs, error logs, etc. It is UDP based, so it is fire and forget from the application servers' standpoint.  It provides nice search/querying tools as well.  Personally I like this approach as it removes log management from the application servers altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Two options that I've used:

- Use syslog (or Syslog-NG) to  log to a centralized location.  We do this to ship our AWS log data offsite to our datacenter.  Syslog-NG is more reliable than plain ole' Syslog and allows us to use MongoDB as a backing store.
- Use logrotate to push your logs to S3.  It's not real-time like the Syslog solution, but it's a lot easier to set up and manage, especially if you have a lot of instances and aren't using a VPC

[Loggly](http://www.loggly.com) and [Splunk Storm](http://www.splunkstorm.com/?ac=storm_splunkdownload) are also two interesting SaaS products intended to solve this problem.